# Intellij csv editor problems with pipes

Tags: csv, intellij-idea, editor

In the version 14.1 of Intellij they have added a csv table like editor, it works fine while you use coma as separator but as soon as you change to any other csv separator like pipes it doesn't work, since several of my values are amounts they have coma so I can't use coma as separator but the tab just won't appear.

Does anyone knows if there is somewhere the separator for this feature can be configured?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't supported in IntelliJ v14.  It does seem to be supported in IntelliJ v15.